# Cakephp One-way relationship

Tags: cakephp, model, relationship

I have Items and Units, and want each Item to have one Unit, but that unit can be used by many.

**Items Table**

> id - int
>
> name - varchar
>
> description - varchar
>
> unit_id - int

**Units Table**

> id - int
>
> name - varchar
>
> description - varchar

**Items Model**

```
var $hasOne = array( 'Units' => array( 'className' => 'Unit' ) );
```

**Units Model**
Nothing, but previously I tried:  `var $belongsTo = array( 'Items' => array( 'className' => 'Item' ) );`

When I'm in the scaffolding (List Items) I get:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Units.item_id' in 'on clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

And in the Edit Item screen, the Units drop-down is empty. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Essentially the Units table are just to populate a drop-down in the Item entry form, but I'd like it to auto-populate in scaffold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Item **belongsTo** a Unit and your Unit **hasMany** Items.

belongsTo - foreign key is in the current model (`unit_id` of Item)
hasMany - foreign key is in the related model
hasOne - foreign key is in the related model and there's only one
hasAndBelongsToMany - foreign keys are in a separate third table